# how to duplicate a file field entry from drupal commerce to another field so it can be previewed

Tags: file, templates, drupal-7

Im looking for a way to copy a file being uploaded to drupal commerce using commerce file/license to another file field in drupal 7. I want to preview audio files being sold on drupal commerce but because of the private file structure that is forced by commerce license, I have to duplicate the file to another field that is public.

Is there a way to copy a file being uploaded to a public directory and also add a database entry for an additional field associated to the content type?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to create a "public mirror" of the file you uploaded.
Not digging to much in code, since commerce_product is an entity we assume we can alter the product whenever it is saved, so you can to as follow:

- create a module and use hook_entity_insert and/or hook_entity_update
- find the file you need, make a public copy
- fill the value of the public file in another field of the same entity